# WordPress autoamtically adds NoFollow Attribute to every external link

Tags: wordpress, hyperlink, external, nofollow

My WordPress site automatically adds

```
rel="nofollow"
```

to every external link inside of a post/page. I deactivated every Plugin and changed to a standard theme and the problem still occurs. I'm using a self-managed server running Plesk. I used to have Yoast as SEO plugin however completely deleting it still didn't solved the issue. I basically have a blank website with a standard wordpress theme with this behaviour... what else might cause this? Thank  you!